# Javascript extract value from key-value pair in object

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following data returned from an API:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "successful": true,
    "userPreferences": [
        {
            "category": "Alerts",
            "preference": {
                "ContentViolations": "true",
                "UserCommentsYou": "true",
                "UserMessagesYou": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "category": "Display",
            "preference": {
                "DateFormat": "mm-dd-yyyy",
                "TimeFormat": "12-hour"
            }
        },
        {
            "category": "EmailList",
            "preference": {
                "ReceiveDailyDigest": "true",
                "ReceiveDealsOffers": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "category": "Privacy",
            "preference": {
                "OtherUsersMessageYou": "true",
                "OtherUsersViewProfile": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "category": "Units",
            "preference": {
                "Measurement": "inches",
                "Weight": "pounds"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to extract a `preference` value from a key value pair. Here is what I have:

```
const result = userPreferences?.filter(x => x.category === "Alerts" && x.preference["UserMessagesYou"]).map(x => x.preference.value);
```

It's returning `string[] | undefined` but I would like it to retutn `string`.

In the example above I would like `result` to have the value "true".

Comment: What is the desired output example?

Comment: In the example above I would like `result` to have the value "true".

Comment: `.filter` returns an Array ... did you want `.find` instead

Comment: But there is no `x.preference.value` Instead the filtered array that is see will contain only `[{
            "category": "Alerts",
            "preference": {
                "ContentViolations": "true",
                "UserCommentsYou": "true",
                "UserMessagesYou": "true"
            }
        }]`. Work with that instead.

Answer (score 1):

it returns undefined because the property **value** does not exist within the **preference** object.

(It's in the last operation that you do within the map function: **.map(x => x.preference.value)**)

According to your validation, the properties you have available are:

- ContentViolations
- UserCommentsYou
- UserMessagesYou

Then you can do something like this:

```
const response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "successful": true,
    "userPreferences": [
        {
            "category": "Alerts",
            "preference": {
                "ContentViolations": "true",
                "UserCommentsYou": "true",
                "UserMessagesYou": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "category": "Display",
            "preference": {
                "DateFormat": "mm-dd-yyyy",
                "TimeFormat": "12-hour"
            }
        },
        {
            "category": "EmailList",
            "preference": {
                "ReceiveDailyDigest": "true",
                "ReceiveDealsOffers": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "category": "Privacy",
            "preference": {
                "OtherUsersMessageYou": "true",
                "OtherUsersViewProfile": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "category": "Units",
            "preference": {
                "Measurement": "inches",
                "Weight": "pounds"
            }
        }
    ]
}

const result = response.userPreferences?.filter(x => x.category === "Alerts" && x.preference["UserMessagesYou"]).map(x => x.preference.UserMessagesYou);
console.log("results ====>")
console.log(result)
```

Property **UserMessagesYou** is accessed on the map:

```
.map(x => x.preference.UserMessagesYou)
```

I hope this answer has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The prop preference does not have a props named value ,so it's undefined

```js
const result = userPreferences?.filter(x => x.category === "Alerts" && x.preference["UserMessagesYou"]).map(x => x.preference.UserMessagesYou).join(' ');
```